# Transparent background, while hiding one view and display it as notification

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a Linear Layout, which consists of 2 children layout 1. Frame 2. Linear

What I want to achieve?

I am trying to display different layout on different situations, but when I am displaying the child Linear layout I want to make it like a notification or overlay that uses only some height and we can see the behind screen and interact with it while displaying the Frame layout I wanna use the default behavior that is using the full screen.

What I have tried so far?

1. Instead of using a single contentView, I tried switching to different View by making these 2 children as 2 different layout files.
2. Added the transparent background to the app using a theme, programmatically changing the color to transparent, and following all other alternatives on stack overflow following similar questions.
3. Tried changing the parent Linear Layout to Frame, Constraint Layouts.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_incoming"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:background="#3F51B5"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/inc_reject_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="79dp"
                android:width="80dp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_phone_hang_up"
                android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="hang up"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                tools:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="249dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/inc_text_caller"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#F8F5F5"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="Maa" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/inc_text_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:text="133-9527-9527" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/inc_answer_btn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:width="80dp"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_phone_pick_up"
                android:drawablePadding="16dp"

                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Answer"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                tools:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context=".activity.DailingActivity">

        <!-- OnGoingCall  -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/on_going"
            android:layout_height="667dp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/dialer_fragment"
            layout="@layout/dialpad_fragment" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Don't know how much you progressed and what exact problem you are facing. If you want to make "@+id/main_incoming" LinearLayout as BG/parent of your popup then try changing its  layout_height="wrap_content" to "match_parent".  for the children you don't want to show set visibility to View.GONE

Comment: @AFA I tried doing that also, but I was not able to achieve that, I tried changing the height of the parent layout to WRAP_CONTENT for notification one and MATCH_PARENT while displaying the other view. But on the notification it was showing the white background ie why I tried changing the background to transparent.